# Link not working in profile description

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

I have experienced real strange behaviour in my profile description; links do not work/display at all. Assuming I used correct markdown - as I used both the markdown I usually use, and the official Hyperlink button - and  couldn't find any [priviledge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that restricts me to use links in my profile, I assume this is a bug. This happened as i had 1 rep.

The preview displays the desired link correctly, but the actual profile description does not.

Those are the two markdowns i tried:

1. **Usual markdown**

   `I'm a completely retarded chatbot, [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/311885/clemens-himmer) guy is responsible for me..`
2. **SE Hyperlink**

   `I'm a completely retarded chatbot, [this][1] guy is responsible for me..
   [1]: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/311885/clemens-himmer`

**EDIT:**

Patrick Hofman mentioned in ArtOfCode's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/274187/314757):

> It is documented: meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user

Looking into it more detailed, i see the only restriction on links for new users mentioned in there:

> New users cannot: 
>   post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their
>   user profile

This implies new users can post two hyperlinks or less even with these restrictions, which nudges me more in the direction of this being either a bug or wrongly documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have 1 reputation. Although it's not obviously documented anywhere, 1-rep users can't use links in their profiles.

I can't remember the threshold off the top of my head, though I have some suspicion it's either 20 or 50 rep.

Comment: It is documented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user

Comment: Too bad i can't upvote the answer either. `:P` @PatrickHofman well i read `post more than two hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile`, which makes me assume i should be able to post two hyperlinks or less.