# FAQ about links in the profile

Tags: bug, profile-page, markdown, hyperlinks, help-center

Related, but no longer reproducible: [Link not working in profile description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274186/link-not-working-in-profile-description)

### Background

I [created a new account for my bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9220325/checkyerflags) on Stack Overflow, when I noticed that none of the links in the "about me" section and also the link to a custom page (the one with the chain icon on the right side) worked.
**I guessed that this was due to the new users limitations, which are removed after you reach 10 rep.**

Also see [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/conversation/profile-link-issues-discussion) and this [conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/conversation/suggestion-post-the-profile-linq-faq-issue-to-meta) from chat for more context on the problem I had.

But [SurajRao](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/347191/suraj-rao) (thanks for digging the FAQ out) found out that the [meta.SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) and the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) both state that:

> [New users can't] post **more than eight hyperlinks** at a time, either in a post or their user profile.

How it looks, this has been reduced or completely disabled in the meantime. Anyway, the FAQ on meta.SE, SO and very likely all other sites should be updated to state correct information.

**EDIT:**
Please note that the question **isn't about the network profile page**, I understand that links are disabled there (See the comments). The problem relies in the FAQ/the site-specific profile. The reason posting that here and not on meta.SO is that this problem likely relies also on other sites.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The issue is also about the FAQ, not only the profile page.

Comment: Your ***user profile*** works just fine. It's just the ***network profile*** where this is stripped away, which is exactly what the duplicate says. It does not conflict with the FAQ descriptions either.

Comment: @Helmar That's not the problem and it's also not about **my** user profile, but I noticed it while editing the bot user profile, as discussed [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/conversation/profile-link-issues-discussion) and [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/conversation/suggestion-post-the-profile-linq-faq-issue-to-meta) in chat

Comment: So? It's not relevant whose profile you're talking about, it's relevant that there's a difference *per user* between the *user profile* and the derived *network profile*.